# Implementing SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

This is my code. 
 I have a text view and 2 buttons accept and reject. When user clicks the accept button I used a shared preference to save the status as 100.

Next time when user login I need to check if the user has already clicked the accept   button.
 If he has already accepted, then I should go to the home activity.

Once the user has clicked the accept I don't need this activity to be displayed again.

```
public int kill;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Toast.makeText(Eula.this, "Status of the app is "+kill, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(kill==100)
    {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("mobi.infoways.triviavs1_0","mobi.infoways.triviavs1_0.Home"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.eulatxt);
    Intent i2 = getIntent();                
    addListenerOnButton();
}
        private void addListenerOnButton() {

        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtv1); 
        t.setText(f);
        Button Accept = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);    
            Accept.setOnClickListener(startListener);
            Button Reject = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);    
            Reject.setOnClickListener(startListener);
}

        OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) {

          switch (v.getId()) {
             case R.id.btn1:

                 SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                 editor.putInt("storedInt",100); 
                 editor.commit();
                     kill = prefs.getInt("storedInt", 100);
                    Toast.makeText(Eula.this, "status =" + kill, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("mobi.infoways.triviavs1_0","mobi.infoways.triviavs1_0.Home"));
                startActivity(intent);
              break;
             case R.id.btn2:
                 Toast.makeText(Eula.this, "button 2 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Eula.this.finish();
              break;
          }  

    };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Use

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourAcitivyName.this);
```

Also in `onCreate()` after the `super` constructor load the preferences and initialize you `kill` variable.

initializing kill in onCreate method next to super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); itself may enough..

Comment: getting an error when i use preference manager.
The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){})

Comment: As I said, you have to load the preferences in the beginning of your `onCreate()` and load the preference to your `kill` variable there... I can't really help you if you are unwilling to think a bit on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Refer below code

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Boolean checkforFirstTime;

sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

checkforFirstTime = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkforFirstTime", true);

//Checking whether application is launched first time
if (checkforFirstTime) {

    //your code
    editor.putBoolean("checkforFirstTime", false);
    editor.commit();

 } else {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

when load shared prefferences call this:

```
SharedPreferences save = getSharedPreferences("login", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
save.getInt(variable, 0); // zero is default value if you dont have it yet saved
```

and when saving call this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("login", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt("storedInt", 100);
editor.commit();
```